# Is there a state-based approach to neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design

It occurred to me that neural networks operate like straight-line programs: an input is processed once by the layers, and an output is always immediately formed, in the same amount of time for each input. There is no branching based on certain features or any analysis of the results, which could be why NNs sometimes output ridiculous things or get fooled by random noise added to an image.

This doesn't seem to be how humans think. We might receive an input and solve/classify it immediately, but for a more difficult problem, we might "stew" on it for a while. The idea goes around and around in our heads while bits of the problem are worked out in steps, and the results from one step aid our ability to solve the next step, until *eventually* we may be confident in an answer. Or maybe one step invalidates a previous step, so we go back to the beginning and try again. Or maybe we never arrive at an answer and decide to terminate our thinking after so much time. Either way, we don't immediately produce an answer to all inputs; some kind of *introspection* goes on, and we assemble our answer based on a series of steps, and this seems to be a more flexible model that I would associate with "intelligence".

Does this idea even make sense? Is there any work on extending the NN model to have some kind of state where the first output might not be good, so the output is re-processed or sent to another NN to try again for a confident answer? I have read about recurrent NNs, but they are not like what I am describing; they are still just one-and-done in the processing stage.